# can a css line contain multiple colons?

Tags: css

I am writing a Python module that will be doing some css manipulations and modifications. As of my knowledge, the css template is:

```
selector{
    property:value;
}
```

my question is, **is there any instance where `value` contains a colon?**

The reason for this is that I want to split the lines inside selectors by a colon and essentially grab the property and the value, but if the value has a colon in it, then the entire function will manipulate the css incorrectly.

Comment: You may be able to render the question moot by splitting first on semicolon or newline (to ensure one property per line), then using `strpos` to locate the first colon and splitting at that point.

Comment: yes that is what I am going to do...`split(':',1)` will do the trick since there are instances

Comment: @RyanSaxe That seems like it will work. Not sure whose css you are validating, but you can put the whole declaration on one line... and sometimes css is malformed. I don't envy you, ha!

Comment: @Gray yes it does work. and I split by either a linebreak or semicolon  and then fix it later. this allows me to write my css and miss semicolons as long as I go to the next line and I essentially reformat the css and try to get it as clean as possible before I start the manipulations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes.

If you specify a filter (IE) it contains a second colon.

Example:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fad59f', endColorstr='#fa9907')
```

Any CSS property that takes a url could easily contain `http:`

Example:

```
background-image: url("http://example.com/image.jpg");
```

Comment: Godammit IE, always breaking the spec. :-P

Answer (score 5):

Yes, for instance:

```
selector:before{
    content:":";
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's a clever one. Really nothing is safe when you consider the content property.